# Implementing Depth First search using Adjacency linked list graph

Tags: c++

I've been trying to implement this algorithm but the code doesn't seem to print all the results for some reason.
Please note that I've represented the graph using linked list.
I've changed the "visted" array to a boolean variable inside the node.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int x;
    node *link;
    bool marked = false;
} *p1, *p2;



void DFS(node *startPoint){
    
    cout<<startPoint->x<<" ";
    startPoint->marked = true;
    while(startPoint->link!= NULL)
    {
        startPoint = startPoint->link;
        if(startPoint->marked == false)
        {
            DFS(startPoint);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int size;
    int depth_first;
    cout<<"Enter number of nodes: ";
    cin>>size;
    node *N[size];
    int edges;
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++ ){
        N[i] = new node;
        cout<<"Enter node #"<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>N[i]->x;
        cout<<"How many edges in node("<<N[i]->x<<")? = ";
        cin>>edges;
        p1 = N[i];
        for(int j =0; j< edges; j++){
            p2 = new node;
            cout<<"Enter edge #"<<j+1<<":";
            cin>>p2->x;
            p1->link = p2;
            p1 = p1->link;
        }
        p2 = NULL;
    }
    
    cout<<"Enter the start of the depth first search: ";
    cin>>depth_first;
    DFS(N[depth_first]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Input:

node 0 = edges 1 2

node 1 = edges 0 1 3

node 2 = edges 0 1

node 3 = edges 1

depth_first = 0

Output:

0 1 2

Comment: This program requires user input, but you did not provide the input that produces the problem, nor did you show what the output is and what output you expect.

Comment: As an aside, variable-length arrays (VLAs) are non-standard C++.  Now is a good time to drop that habit, and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say the problem is that you never set `marked` to true.  This looks like a basic logic error.  Very clearly, if your graph contains cycles then your recursion will be endless...  at least until you blow out the stack and crash.  The other issue is that if you have nodes in your graph that are not reachable from the starting point, then you will not span the graph with a single call to `DFS`.  If your intent is to visit all nodes (even in a graph containing disjoint sets), then you'll need to start `DFS` from every node.

Comment: consider this graph 
0 -> 1 -> 2
1 ->  0 -> 2 -> 3
2 -> 0 -> 1
3 -> 1

when I pick 0 as the source
The program output is will be = 0 1 2
it doesn't print the last node

Comment: Well you won't hit the final list node because your loop stops when it sees the next-pointer is NULL.  Speaking of which....  You never initialize that, so your program has undefined behavior anyway.  You're probably getting NULL by pure luck (or by compiling without optimizations).

Comment: @AhmedKahil `node *N[size];` --> Change that to `std::vector<node *> N(size);`